# IBM Worklight 6.1 - dojox.data.ItemExplorer widget

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, dojo, worklight-studio

I was working on a hybrid app this weekend using Dojo v1.9.1 in Worklight 6.1.

I found that adding an `ItemExplorer` (dojox.data.ItemExplorer) widget to the project created an error that disabled the `MobileNavigation` panel.

Further research revealed that `ItemExplorer` is not found in Dojo docs starting at v1.8.

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: No question Scott, I want to make people aware of this issue and help them avoid bugs.

Comment: Then have you done anything with this information [here](https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/)?

Comment: ItemExplorer is no longer listed in the Dojo documentation, probably because it is not currently functional. The Worklight Dojo Palette contains an ItemExplorer widget, which is non functional and will create errors in your code. I have already notified the Worklight folks about this. I don't see how Dojo bug reporting comes into play here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is to notify that the Dojox Widgets section in the Palette view contains this removed widget?

Indeed it seems that [`dojox.data.ItemExplorer`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.7/dojox/data/ItemExplorer) does no longer exist starting [Dojo 1.8](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.8).
I've opened a defect to see why it is listed.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. dojox/data/ItemExplorer still exists (https://github.com/dojo/dojox/blob/master/data/ItemExplorer.js). The question needs to be clarified.

Comment: Then why is it not documented?